# Об употреблении слов "а", "не", "но"

Tags: семантика

Предположим на столике лежат туз, король, дама, валет.

Верно ли, что указание "Возьми короля, а не туза." означает указание "Возьми короля, но не бери туза."?

Answer (score 1):

Данное указание верно.

Comment: Большое спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, что возьми именно короля.

Comment: Видимо, Вы правы.